# Finding the Jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^7\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^7$ a linear map such that $(T-22I)^3=0$ and $\dim\text{Im}(T-22I)^2=2$
>   
>   Find the Jordan normal form of the matrix.

So the characteristic polynomial is $(x-22)^7$ therefore there are the eigenvalue $22$ appear a total number of $7$ times.

Because  $(T-22I)^3=0$ and $\dim\text{Im}(T-22I)^2=2$, therefore $(x-22)^2\neq$ 0 and the minimal polynomial is $(T-22I)^3=0$ so the biggest block of $22$ is of the size of $3$.
We also know that each block will be less of equal to the size of $3$, but how do I know the sizes the blocks of the left $4$ eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2):

How does the fact that $\dim (T - 22I)^2 = 2$ help you find out the number of blocks of size 2 and 3?

Comment: it is the $dim(im(T-22I)^2=2$ so the $dim(Ker(T-22I)^2)=5$. But it is not a minimal polynomial, so what can I learn from it?

Comment: So, the kernel is 5. How much of the kernel is contributed by each block of size 1, of size 2, and of size 3?

Comment: So that means the there are $5$ blocks of $22$? because $5$ is the geometric multiplication of the eigenvalue $22$

Comment: Not exactly. The block of size 1 contributes 1 to the kernel, since when looking at $T - 22I$ that block becomes zero so $(T - 22I)^2$ has a zero in that block. What happens when you do the same thing with a block of size 2 or a block of size 1? Draw the matrices out and see what happens.

Comment: What does " The block of size 1 contributes 1 to the kernel" mean? I know that the $dim(ker(T-\lambda)$ is the number of blocks of $\lambda$

Comment: I mean this: Let $A$ be the following $4\times 4$ matrix. $\begin{pmatrix} 22  & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 22 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 22\end{pmatrix}$, then we see that looking at $A - 22I$ we get $\begin{pmatrix} 0  & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, so the block of size $1$ at the top contributes one dimension to the kernel of $A - 22I$ and the block of size two contributes $1$ as well to the kernel of size $A - 22I$, since those are the columns of zeros. You can do a similar analysis for matrices of different size, like your $7\times 7$ problem.